# Passing a commented, multi-line (freespace) regex to preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex that is going to end up being a bit long and it'd make it much easier to read to have it across multiple lines.

I tried this but it just barfs.

```
preg_match(
    '^J[0-9]{7}:\s+
    (.*?)             #Extract the Transaction Start Date msg
    \s+J[0-9]{7}:\s+Project\sname:\s+
    (.*?)             #Extract the Project Name
    \s+J[0-9]{7}:\s+Job\sname:\s+
    (.*?)             #Extract the Job Name
    \s+J[0-9]{7}:\s+',
    $this->getResultVar('FullMessage'),
    $atmp
);
```

Is there are way to pass a regex in the above form to preg_match?

Comment: Interesting.  Putting tags separated by a + shows them individually in the question but a combined AND tag on the right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the extended syntax:

```
preg_match("/
    test
/x", $foo, $bar);
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can add the `/x` [Pattern Modifier](http://us.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

> This modifier turns on additional
>   functionality of PCRE that is
>   incompatible with Perl. Any backslash
>   in a pattern that is followed by a
>   letter that has no special meaning
>   causes an error, thus reserving these
>   combinations for future expansion. By
>   default, as in Perl, a backslash
>   followed by a letter with no special
>   meaning is treated as a literal. There
>   are at present no other features
>   controlled by this modifier.

For your example try this:

```
preg_match('/
              ^J[0-9]{7}:\s+
              (.*?)             #Extract the Transaction Start Date msg
              \s+J[0-9]{7}:\s+Project\sname:\s+
              (.*?)             #Extract the Project Name
              \s+J[0-9]{7}:\s+Job\sname:\s+
              (.*?)             #Extract the Job Name
              \s+J[0-9]{7}:\s+
            /x', $this->getResultVar('FullMessage'), $atmp);
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, here's a solution:

```
preg_match(
                '/(?x)^J[0-9]{7}:\s+
                (.*?)             #Extract the Transaction Start Date msg
                \s+J[0-9]{7}:\s+Project\sname:\s+
                (.*?)             #Extract the Project Name
                \s+J[0-9]{7}:\s+Job\sname:\s+
                (.*?)             #Extract the Job Name
                \s+J[0-9]{7}:\s+/'
                , $this->getResultVar('FullMessage'), $atmp);
```

The key is **(?x)** at the beginning which makes whitespace insignificant and allows comments.

It's also important that there's no whitespace between the starting and ending quotes and the start & end of the regex.

My first attempt like this gave errors:

```
preg_match('
                /(?x)^J[0-9]{7}:\s+
                (.*?)             #Extract the Transaction Start Date msg
                \s+J[0-9]{7}:\s+Project\sname:\s+
                (.*?)             #Extract the Project Name
                \s+J[0-9]{7}:\s+Job\sname:\s+
                (.*?)             #Extract the Job Name
                \s+J[0-9]{7}:\s+/
           ', $this->getResultVar('FullMessage'), $atmp);
```

What [Konrad said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22552/passing-a-commented-multi-line-freespace-regex-to-pregmatch#22572) also works and feels a little easier than sticking **(?x)** at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

- You should add delimiters: the first character of the regex will be used to indicate the end of the pattern.
- You should add the 'x' flag. This has the same result as putting (?x) at the beginning, but it is more readable imho.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP the comment syntax looks like this:

```
(?# Your comment here)
```

```
preg_match('
            ^J[0-9]{7}:\s+
            (.*?)             (?#Extract the Transaction Start Date msg)
            \s+J[0-9]{7}:\s+Project\sname:\s+
            (.*?)             (?#Extract the Project Name)
                \s+J[0-9]{7}:\s+Job\sname:\s+
            (.*?)             (?#Extract the Job Name)
            \s+J[0-9]{7}:\s+
            ', $this->getResultVar('FullMessage'), $atmp);
```

For more information see the [PHP Regular Expression Syntax Reference](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.php)

You can also use the PCRE_EXTENDED (or 'x') [Pattern Modifier](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) as Mark shows in his example.